# Read Column from text file by c#

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files

I have this text file

```
688.63        C         1          C        0          0         0
698.70        C         1          C        0          0         0
708.89        C         1          C        0          0         0
716.78        C         1          C        0          0         0
718.97        C         1          C        0          0         0
728.27        C         1          C        0          0         0
728.89        C         1          C        0          0         0
738.82        C         1          C        0          0         0
759.00        C         1          C        0          0         0
```

The question is how to read every column in this array? and what about if I want to access a specific value of a column? Like the second value of the first column.

Comment: What do you want the array to look like? Post a C# declaration. The columns look like they should have different types.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183355/reading-integers-from-a-text-file-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> Opens a text file, **reads all lines of the file**, and then closes the
>   file.

Example from MSDN;

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

This will create an array that keeps as a string line by line.

> and what about if i want to acess specific value of column ? like
>   value 2 of column one

If all values has the same space between them, you can use `String.Split` method like;

```
string s = "688.63        C         1          C        0          0         0";
var array = s.Split(new string[]{"        "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(array[1]); // Prints "C"
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/XQKqxJ)</kbd>.

In your case, you can use;

```
var array = lines[1].Split(new string[]{"        "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(array[0]); // Prints "698.70"
```

`line[1]` get you second line on your text and `array[0]` gets you first value of this line which is `698.70`.

> i want it to print like this 688.63 698.70 708.89 all values of first
>   column to appear not just firs value.

You can use `foreach` like;

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach(var line in lines)
{
  var firstValue = line.Split(new string[]{"        "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
  Console.WriteLine(firstValue);
}
```

Comment: Not nearly a complete answer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yeap. Update is coming..

Comment: then how to split every column alone ???

Comment: @HenkHolterman How about now?

Comment: @user1477332 Updated in my answer. You can use `String.Split` method.

Comment: last upadate already works but what if i want to edit all values in same time 
i want it to print like this 
688.63
698.70
708.89 
all values of first column to appear not just firs value

Comment: @user1477332 Updated. Take a look.

Comment: column 1 and column 2 appears not just 1

Comment: @user1477332 It shouldn't appears. Are you sure you use `var firstValue = line.Split(new string[]{"        "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];` ? Don't forget to use `[0]` at the end. It gets the first value of line.

Comment: done now it appears ... the problem was in this line new string[]{"        "}  .... we must decrease spaces between quotes. 

another quetion what if i want to export this column to another text file

Comment: @user1477332 That's not a part of the question. Ask it as another question. If one of these answers solved your problem, consider to accept one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: lol i forgot to accept it , sorry for that ,,, now accepted , thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

You can use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> File.ReadAllLines returns an array. This array contains a string for
>   each line in the file specified. We use this method. We then look
>   inside its .NET Framework implementation to see how it works. It is
>   found in the System.IO namespace.
>   Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file, and then closes the
>   file.

The [File.ReadAllLines](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readalllines) method is not a low-level implementation. Instead, it uses a List and the StreamReader type, and then ToArray, to return the array. This is inefficient if you want to put a file into a List.

If you need to optimize a File.ReadAllLines call, you could estimate the capacity of the List in its constructor, which would reduce resizes. You could also avoid ToArray if you want to keep the List.

[List Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)

[Using StreamReader](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader)

[ToArray Extension Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/toarray)

[Capacity Property](http://www.dotnetperls.com/capacity)

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499893/how-to-properly-read-columns-from-text-file):

```
string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach(string record in records)
{
  DataRow r = myDataTable.NewRow();
  string[] fields = record.Split('\t');
  /* Parse each field into the corresponding r column
   * ....
   */
  myDataTable.rows.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: `File.ReadLines()` would be an optimization for (very) large files.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ok Waite please

Comment: i got error in this myDataTable ??

Comment: @user1477332 What is your error?

Comment: what is the reference for it ??
The name 'myDataTable' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user1477332 see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421745/how-to-read-text-file-specifications-row-and-column-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need `two dimensional array`

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path");

 string[][] myRecords = new string[lines.Count()+1][];
 int k = 1;
 foreach (var line in lines)
 {
     var values = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
     {
        if (myRecords[k] == null) myRecords[k] = new string[values.Length+1];
        myRecords[k][i] = values[i];
     }
     k++;
   }
```

Then you can access a value for example row 1 column 3:

```
myRecord[1][3]
```

Comment: error in myRecords[k][i] = values[i];
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in read rows or column in text file.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

So have more answers for this

[how to read text file specifications row and column in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421745/how-to-read-text-file-specifications-row-and-column-in-c-sharp)

[How to properly read columns from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499893/how-to-properly-read-columns-from-text-file)

[How to read a Chinese text file from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336781/how-to-read-a-chinese-text-file-from-c?rq=1)

and you can found more solutions in google

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Record class and then use a simple LINQ query:

`var records = File.ReadLines("file.txt")
    .Select(line =>
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split('\t');
            return new Record
                {
                    column1 = int.Parse(parts[0]),
                    column2= parts[1],
                    column3= int.Parse(parts[2]),
                    column4= parts[3],
                    column5= int.Parse(parts[4]),
                    column6= int.Parse(parts[5]),
                    column7= int.Parse(parts[6])
                };
        }).ToArray();`

This will give you a bunch of Records, one per line in the original file.You can then select columns in the record like this

`var allColumn1s = records.Select(rec => rec.column1);`